# Given a date return previous Sunday

Tags: linux, bash, date

I know how to calculate the previous Sunday `date -dlast-sunday +%Y-%m-%d` and how to add or remove days(weeks/years) from a given date with `date +%Y-%m-%d --date "2017-10-10 +3 day"`. What I cannot achieve is to get the previous Sunday when the input is a give date.

I already tried

`date -d -dlast-sunday +%Y-%m-%d --date "2017-12-15"
date +%Y-%m-%d --date "2017-10-10 -dlast-sunday"`

Comment: @JNevill I promise that I did my research before post and I couldn't find it

Comment: no worries. That's an automated comment when we flag to close as a potential duplicate. It's nice to have them flagged if they are a duplicate so that the next person searching with this question and hits this page will be able to be redirected to other answers in the duplicate flagged post. It's a feature, not a hand slap or anything :) In other words, we're as much committed to helping folks get the answer they need as we are to making sure folks in the future can get that same answer, it's a curation like thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%u`, to know how many days you need to subtract to get to the previous Sunday. For example like this:

```
d=2017-10-10 ; u=$(date +%u --date $d) ; date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$d -$u day"
```